# Why does this not insert new rows when there are already rows with the same properties?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why does:

```
INSERT INTO tableex (C1, C2) 
SELECT null, 'stringtext' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableex WHERE C1 = null AND C2 = 'stringtext');
```

insert a new row when a row with C1 = null and C2 = 'stringtext' already exists? How can this be fixed so it only inserts if a row with the same property is not in the table.

Comment: I don't know enough about postgresql but in standard sql you can't test for equality with null. Use `is null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableex WHERE C1 = null AND C2 = 'stringtext')
```

`c1 = null` evaluates to `null`. `not exists` evaluates to `true` and hence inserts values into the table.

You should use `c1 is null` instead.

Comment: that is not the full statement to be run. I just showed where you were wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for `C1 = NULL`, but you need to use:

```
C1 IS NULL
```

SQL considers a null not to be equal to another null